# Installing OpenNI on Pcduino

Tags: kinect, robotic-arm, openni

Following my [previous question about pcduino+kinect](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2649/kinect-point-cloud-pcduino-will-it-work), decided to go ahead and buy the pcduino I wish to run my robot with (kinect+pcduino+shields). However I'm having trouble getting started: I tried installing OpenNI, NITE and SensorKinect however OpenNI installation fails (I haven't even gotten to installing NITE and SensorKinect yet so no idea if that would work). I tried a bunch of pointers ([here](http://daybydaylinux.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-compile-openni-and-sensorkinect.html) and [here](http://www.andol.info/hci/1924.htm)). For example the error I get if I follow link 1 is:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist \$ sudo ./RedistMaker.Arm
>
> Target: Linux-Arm
>
> Version: 1.5.7.10
>
> Num of compile jobs: 0
>
> - Building OpenNI...
>
> Common/CommonDefs.mak:36: *** Cross-Compilation error. Can't find ARM-J1_CXX and >ARM-J1_STAGING.  Stop.
>
> failed to execute: make PLATFORM=Arm-j1 -C
>
> /home/ubuntu/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/../Build clean
>
> /home/ubuntu/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/Output/BuildOpenNI_clean.txt
>
> Cleaning Failed!
>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist$

After someone suggested it, I tried removing the -mfloat-abi=softfp option but that didn't help. There seems to be some compiling/linking issue due to float types which I'm not able to figure out. In link 1 the author mentions to remove the 'calc_jobs_number()' but that does not work and I get similar error. Also similar problem exists for link 2 above

If I follow link 2, 'make' won't work and will give the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: error: ../../Bin/Arm-Release/libOpenNI.so uses VFP register >arguments, ./Arm-Release/tinyxmlparser.o does not
>   /usr/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file ./Arm-Release/tinyxmlparser.o

Another approach would be to use simpleCV instead of OpenNI on pcduino as someone else claims it has worked before. However I've never used simpleCV with Kinect before so unless it's not radically different I prefer using OpenNI.

Any suggestions as to why I might be getting these errors are appreciated. Any other pointers for solving the problem of installing OpenNI on Pcduino would be welcome.

Please let me know if you need more details about anything else.
Thanks in advance